# Will a Custom font be available in another Device

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt5

I am using pyqt5 to make a software. I used Consolas font but I needed to download and install it first so my question is will the programme work just fine in another Device which does not have the font installe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing fonts is a know problem and QFont uses a fallback if glyphs are not present:

From [QFont - Detailed description](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QFont.html#detailed-description) (emphasis mine)

> When you create a QFont object you specify various attributes that you want the font to have. Qt will use the font with the specified attributes, or if **no matching font** exists, Qt will **use the closest matching** installed font.
>
> [...]
>
> The font matching algorithm works as follows:
>
> 1. The specified font families (set by setFamilies() ) are searched for.
> 2. If not found, then if set the specified font family exists and can be used to represent the writing system in use, it will be selected.
> 3. If not, a replacement font that supports the writing system is selected. The font matching algorithm will try to find the best match for all the properties set in the QFont . How this is done varies from platform to platform.
> 4. If no font exists on the system that can support the text, then special “missing character” boxes will be shown in its place.
>
> Note
>
> If the selected font, though supporting the writing system in general, is missing glyphs for one or more specific characters, then Qt will try to find a fallback font for this or these particular characters. This feature can be disabled using NoFontMerging style strategy.

See:

- https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QFont.html